# Automation testing : How to start the Java Swing application with RemoteSwingLibrary with python in pycharm?

Tags: python, swing, pycharm, robotframework, ui-automation

I need to do automation testing for  the java swing application. I am using remoteswinglibrary with robot framework in python. I am using Pycharm IDE. My python version is 3.12.1 . I downloaded remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2 jar, and added in my project structure in pycharm. Also i added that jar in environment variables as PYTHONPATH (this is previously recommended in stackoverflow) . But i am not able to launch the application.

I imported library as below.

*** Settings ***
Library     RemoteSwingLibrary

My file type is .JNLP
I need to start that with javaws myfile.jnlp command. How can i start this application using python in pycharm. I have no source code in my local. Now i am starting the application in command line using path/to/my/file javaws myfile.jnlp. How can i start that application in python + robot framework to automate in python.

Previously I tried to start one jar file as below.

*** Test Cases ***
Launch Application
start application   java -jar  myjar

I run it using robot loginTest.robot command. I faced the below error. But the keyword is present in library. No error in code. While running the code, below error is arising.

```
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\RemoteSwingLibrary.py:284: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\$'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\RemoteSwingLibrary.py:286: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\$'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\RemoteSwingLibrary.py:284: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\$'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\RemoteSwingLibrary.py:286: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\$'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:233: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:240: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:252: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:358: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:388: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:390: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:391: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:392: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:394: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:395: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:396: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:405: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:233: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:240: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:252: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:358: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:388: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:390: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:391: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:392: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:394: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:395: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:396: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
C:\Users\padmeshp\Downloads\remoteswinglibrary-2.3.2.jar\swinglibrary.py:405: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\`'
[ ERROR ] Error in library 'RemoteSwingLibrary': Adding keyword 'system_exit' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'
[ ERROR ] Error in library 'RemoteSwingLibrary': Adding keyword 'start_application' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'
[ ERROR ] Error in library 'RemoteSwingLibrary': Adding keyword 'application_started' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'
[ ERROR ] Error in library 'RemoteSwingLibrary': Adding keyword 'switch_to_application' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'
[ ERROR ] Error in library 'RemoteSwingLibrary': Adding keyword 'ensure_application_should_close' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'
[ ERROR ] Error in library 'RemoteSwingLibrary': Adding keyword 'log_java_system_properties' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'
[ ERROR ] Error in library 'RemoteSwingLibrary': Adding keyword 'set_java_tool_options' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'
[ ERROR ] Error in library 'RemoteSwingLibrary': Adding keyword 'reinitiate' failed: Calling dynamic method 'get_keyword_arguments' failed: AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'
==============================================================================
loginTest
==============================================================================
Launch Application                                                    | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'start application' found.
```

Tell me if I did the steps wrongly in setting up this environment.

[Note : Is it fine to go with remoteswinglibrary, else kindly suggest any other best automation tool for testing java swing application.]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably facing some problems:

- Using \ for path separator (Windows), that is why the error message
- Using Python 3.12 for a library that may not be compatible with (yet)
- Newest RobotFramework version 7.0 may also cause problems

You could try to do a setup with Cygwin, or trying a setup in PowerShell (newer version, Linux like).
First thing you should try is to run the remotelibrary.jar to see if it runs OK. Probably includes some demo. Or, you can try to run the SwingLibrary jar app.

Comment: Hi Helio, 
   I run remoteswniglibrary-2.3.2.jar separately, it is launching. But in python it is not launching. If we need to use swinglibrary means, we need to use jython right ? I am trying to automate in python. Some people in github syaing that, they are able to launch jnlp application in robotframework with RemoteSwingLibrary in python. Is there any other way ?

Comment: RemoteSwingLibrary should be the way to go. Try to have a setup that proves it works with a sample project, then go for your real project.

Comment: Previously i added remoteswinglibrary.jar in my environment variables. After that, jar is displaying under my External Libraries folder in project. But i cant able to import library.

robotframework version - 7
python version - 3.12.1
remote swing library ja version - 2.3.3.

Is this version have any problem in setting the environment ?

Comment: After changing the python version to 3.10.10, i am launch the application. Thankyou very much for your help.

Also in that , i used start application keyword to start, but it is showing "Agent port not received to before timeout". Kindly help me in this case. Now i am using start process keyword to launch.

Comment: @Helio some of the rows where SyntaxError are coming are *not* path separators but from escape sequences.   And rows with ERROR's are basicly because of *deprecated* inspect.getargspec() has now been removed in 3.11.

Answer (score 0):

inspect.getargspec()  shall be updated to  inspect.getfullargspec(), package in a new jar and use the new jar in yout pythonpath. You shall get rid of the errors.